# jq-win64.exe: Parsing data from a JSON file in Windows Batch File

Tags: json, batch-file, command-line, jq

I have the following JSON file (song.json) that contains:

```json
{
  "Result": [
    {
      "ItemTitle": "Sometimes It Hurts",
      "Artists": [
        "Voost"
      ],
      "MediaEnd": "00:02:15.8490000",
      "Extro": "00:02:12.8200000",
      "MediaId": 9551,
      "ActualLength": "00:02:12.8200000",
      "ItemType": "Song"
    },
    {
      "ItemTitle": "Been a Long Time (Full Intention 2021 Remix)",
      "Artists": [
        "The Fog"
      ],
      "MediaEnd": "00:03:11.3170000",
      "IntroEnd": "00:00:07.4700000",
      "Extro": "00:03:08.6300000",
      "MediaId": 9489,
      "ActualLength": "00:03:08.6300000",
      "ItemType": "Song"
    }
  ],
  "ExceptionMessage": null,
  "FailMessage": null,
  "ExceptionTypeName": null
}
```

I want to extract the first “ItemTitle” and the first “Artist” and save them as variables.

In this example the result I am looking for would be:

```
ItemTitle=Sometimes It Hurts

Artist=Voost
```

I have been trying to use jq-win64.exe as this needs to run in a Windows Batch File, but I can’t get the syntax right. I have tried various examples that I have found on here but none of them appears to work as required. Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: You can use `jq -r 'Result[].ItemTitle, Result[].Artist song.json'` in order to extract the values of the desired parts.

Comment: Excuse me, realised that I left a typo. Use `jq -r .Result[].ItemTitle, .Result[].Artists[] song.json`. HAve a look at [this](https://jqplay.org/s/u6lARsz-mo)

Comment: @Barbaros Özhan - Thanks but I get the error: jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER, expecting $end (Windows cmd shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1: 'Result[].ItemTitle, jq: 1 compile error

Comment: I'm sorry but I still get the same error message.

Comment: I think perhaps jq is different from jq-win64 because I still get the same error. However, your example on jqplay does not produce what I am looking for. I need the FIRST ItemTitle and Artist only. The second one needs to be ignored.

Comment: Yes, it might be. I use that command line tool on linux. Btw, `jq  -r .Result[0].ItemTitle, .Result[0].Artists[]` will extract the first components. [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/pNWk5xAQ_m)

Answer (score 0):

First things first.

Since you seem to be having trouble on several fronts , I would suggest that you first get your jq query working the way you want
by using jq with the -f command-line option.  That way, you can write your query without having to worry about
Windows rules for escaping characters on the command line.  When the results are as you wish, you might even to decide to
leave well-enough alone.

Next, to obtain the values you want, it would seem you will want a jq query like this:

```
.Result | first(.[].ItemTitle), first(.[].Artists[])
```

With your JSON, this produces:

```
Sometimes It Hurts
Voost
```

But you say you want these values in the KEY=VALUE form.  This can be achieved by modifying the basic query, e.g. as follows:

```
.Result|"ItemTitle=\(first(.[].ItemTitle))", "Artist=\(first(.[].Artists[]))"
```

Somehow I doubt this is really what you want, but the rest should be clear sailing.

Comment: With help from @Barbaros Özhan, we have established that the correct filter is:

`--raw-output '.Result[0].ItemTitle, .Result[0].Artists[]'`

However, I am using jq-win64.exe in a Windows command line and when I enter the following:

`jq-win64 --raw-output '.Result[0].ItemTitle, .Result[0].Artists[]' song.json`
I get:

`jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER, expecting $end (Windows cmd shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
'.Result[0].ItemTitle,
jq: 1 compile error`

I think I am almost there so any further guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: cmd.exe only recognizes double quotes, not single quotes.